# Debugging Python script in VS Code results in error: "macOS 11 (1107) or later required, have instead 11 (1106)"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tkinter

I am debugging a Python script with VS Code.

Pyenv indicates that I am running Python 3.10.2:

```
pyenv versions
  system
  3.7.7
  3.8.2
  3.9.1
* 3.10.12 (set by /Users/scason/.python-version)
  3.11.4
```

The Python script is using Tkinter.

The following is basically the essential code...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
##
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


def genPW ():
    root = Tk()    <=== this is where I get the error 


    root.mainloop()


def main() :
    genPW()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

I might add that the Python script does run and I am able to debug it in an Eclipse Python perspective.

I have tried (re)setting peenv with different versions.  I expect to be able to debug the script.

Comment: This is not a complaint about your Python version.  Your Python is saying that your version of MacOS is too old, which it is.  You have 11.06, released 2 years ago.  https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/580

Answer (score 0):

**"macOS 11 (1107) or later required, have instead 11 (1106)"**

It requires macOS 11.0.7 or later, but your computer is running macOS 11.0.6.

You can use the following steps to update your macOS:

1. Click on the Apple menu in the top left corner of your screen and select "System Preferences".
2. Click on "Software Update".
3. If an update is available, click on "Update Now" to download and install the update.
4. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the update process.